# IF contains with multiple other conditions

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

this is from a none programmer
I have the  formula below that checks 3 conditions

```
=IF((AND(H2="DWL",K2<=0,W2<>"")), "Send Email", "Wait")
H2= DWL
K2 is Less than 1
W2 is occupied
```

But I am trying to get so if H2 contains “DWL” plus the other 2 criteria’s are correct

Eg, `H2 may contain “DWL1234”, “DWL5678” “DWL25643” or “DWLJHRER”`

Comment: use `REGEXMATCH` do you want to use the google app script for that or just use formula?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, is there not a symbol for contains as in = for equal too, > for larger than etc..

Comment: you tagged `google-apps-script` and `google-sheets-api`which are different than using a simple formula in your cell. Do you want to use a formula or do you want to script it. If I've well understanded your problem you need to use `REGEX` matching to check if the string in your cell contains **DWL**

Comment: if the content of your cell is based on other cell you can always use nested condition formulas `IF(AND(IF(,,,),,),,)`

Comment: It's not clear what programing language is this question about. Please clarify is are looking for help with a Google Sheets formula, [tag:google-apps-script]/[tag:javascript] or another language. Note: [tag:google-sheets-api] could be used with several languages.

Comment: It´s for a condition in Appsheet Addon linked to google sheets so I am guessing Java

Comment: I eventuly worked it out with what JSmith surgested       =IF((AND(OR(I3="YT DWL",I3="YT DWL"),M3<=0,AD3<>"")), "Send Email", "Wait")     Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will do the trick :

```
=IF((AND(REGEXMATCH(H2,"DWL"),K2<=0,W2="occupied")), "Send Email", "Wait")
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: The occupied bit didn´t work but replacing it with <>"" did it ie=IF((AND(REGEXMATCH(H2,"DWL"),K2<=0,W2=<>"")), "Send Email", "Wait") Thanks alot Grzegorz Mogilewski